# (Chrome bug?) pointer-events : none , prevents scrolling underneath on Chrome Android 78

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, pointer-events

[UPDATE], bug filed : https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1011866&q=pointer-events&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

I realised that now on Chrome 78.0.3904, (Android 9), applying `pointer-events:none` to a fixed position overlaying element is preventing the elements underneath from being scrolled.

I employ this technique alot in the sites i make and its been working fine till i realised that this is broken today. But it still works fine on all other devices and browsers. Safari on IOS for example.

I did a simple test that i attached below, and you can try on android chrome browsers to see the issue.

Heres also an external url with the same test : https://www.fariskassim.com/stage/rebel9/democracy_museum/sandbox/chrome_bug/

```css
  .overlay {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      z-index: 10;
      background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
      pointer-events: none;
  }

  .scrollable_content {
   position: fixed;
   top:0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;;
   overflow:auto;
  }
```

```html
 <div class="overlay"></div>

 <div class="scrollable_content">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam laoreet justo at sapien vulputate, dictum pellentesque turpis ultricies. Quisque pellentesque maximus ultrices. Vivamus tempus sem vehicula varius laoreet. Donec gravida sit amet lorem ac molestie. Nunc eget lobortis turpis. Praesent fringilla quam non ligula bibendum, vel consectetur orci lobortis. Morbi a efficitur augue. Donec in nisl pellentesque, scelerisque arcu non, dictum augue.

  Nam purus augue, auctor vitae purus et, gravida viverra velit. Vivamus a massa euismod, luctus leo sed, maximus eros. Phasellus egestas varius euismod. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Cras pretium magna a justo vestibulum, mattis efficitur enim consequat. Nunc malesuada leo sed turpis rhoncus cursus. Phasellus mollis elementum magna ac varius.

  Sed varius dui non leo fermentum, eu aliquet risus bibendum. Duis ac diam tellus. Nullam eleifend sed dui eu iaculis. Nulla nec ultrices turpis, at tempor enim. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Etiam venenatis porttitor mauris, et consequat tortor euismod quis. Donec at tortor convallis, convallis urna eu, fermentum justo.

  Cras egestas, turpis eget sodales egestas, lacus erat hendrerit diam, id dapibus augue enim sit amet justo. Nullam a augue ac diam convallis placerat at id lacus. In eu ipsum dui. Nunc lacinia molestie ligula, id suscipit erat. Praesent euismod eget nunc non facilisis. Aenean quis ipsum egestas, dictum sem sit amet, vestibulum arcu. Phasellus pretium id sem a euismod. Fusce eu ornare purus. Vestibulum porttitor augue a suscipit volutpat. Curabitur sodales urna libero, sed posuere odio lacinia ut. Cras quis mauris augue.

  Ut augue quam, elementum non ante in, blandit lacinia ex. Vestibulum in lectus pulvinar, faucibus nisi tincidunt, placerat dolor. Ut lacinia risus nunc, eget blandit dolor malesuada in. Donec at urna ac orci pulvinar lobortis. Donec aliquet ex nec faucibus suscipit. Nulla libero arcu, efficitur ut elit vel, congue egestas massa. Etiam laoreet odio leo, ut vehicula nunc consequat fringilla. Nam arcu mauris, vehicula sed sagittis a, sodales et felis. Pellentesque in hendrerit orci. Sed ornare tristique turpis sed ultrices.

  Aliquam mollis mi sit amet ex lacinia, sed sollicitudin ipsum efficitur. Ut elementum vulputate luctus. Duis id mollis eros. Praesent pellentesque, augue nec vestibulum finibus, est elit faucibus quam, eu condimentum dui mi at erat. Duis varius ullamcorper auctor. Suspendisse potenti. Mauris quis justo venenatis, lacinia diam eu, gravida augue. Ut in magna arcu. Etiam nec arcu ex. Phasellus ut nibh leo. Proin consectetur lacus risus, et sodales nisi luctus placerat. Maecenas eget fringilla sem, vitae sagittis nisi. Mauris et maximus velit. Fusce a velit sed quam porttitor suscipit vitae nec lectus.

  Nulla lobortis ligula condimentum elit pellentesque vulputate. Aenean ac nisl in metus tincidunt viverra. Integer risus urna, fringilla ac metus ac, congue feugiat nulla. Donec dui risus, gravida eu tempor iaculis, vulputate at ante. Donec cursus elit ac ipsum pretium, non dapibus arcu vehicula. Nulla porttitor urna a lectus molestie, vitae dictum enim varius. Sed justo turpis, rhoncus eget tortor ut, rhoncus condimentum ante. Nulla erat est, interdum pulvinar diam vitae, fringilla interdum risus. Donec maximus, nisl ac tristique tincidunt, lacus metus posuere nisl, a viverra ante dolor in libero. Donec eleifend congue lectus. Maecenas sed mattis nisl. Vivamus lectus eros, interdum eu congue quis, fermentum at odio. Nullam maximus ligula in posuere viverra. Donec vitae consequat nisi. Fusce nibh ex, aliquam et erat a, varius congue nisi.

  Integer tristique sodales enim at ultrices. Integer at lobortis felis. Maecenas et justo imperdiet justo tempor dapibus. Donec convallis tortor sit amet commodo condimentum. Sed maximus ipsum nec sapien cursus, id molestie est sodales. Curabitur nisi justo, scelerisque vitae sagittis at, ultricies at odio. Nulla commodo libero eros, quis convallis tortor finibus quis. Vivamus ipsum lorem, tristique eu lobortis vitae, imperdiet sit amet ipsum. Sed eget volutpat lacus. Phasellus sit amet sapien lacus. Mauris sollicitudin facilisis sapien, bibendum ornare libero ultricies non. Vivamus magna augue, maximus vitae turpis vitae, tincidunt ornare magna. Donec aliquet diam nec lobortis imperdiet. Sed non tellus a est laoreet pharetra. Donec eleifend porta nisl, ac euismod elit fermentum at.

  Vestibulum maximus dui sed nisi sollicitudin, quis lacinia lectus viverra. Praesent dictum viverra ipsum ut finibus. Proin eget accumsan nulla. Nulla finibus viverra orci, a rhoncus enim condimentum vitae. Vivamus lacinia eros ante, in pellentesque diam sodales sit amet. Ut ut nibh ex. Proin aliquet ornare erat. Suspendisse ullamcorper condimentum libero nec molestie. Quisque fringilla lectus neque, at suscipit ex congue nec. Nullam accumsan vitae nisi eget lobortis. Pellentesque quis imperdiet dui, non porttitor ante. Mauris ipsum ante, accumsan commodo vulputate ut, fringilla id mauris. Duis pretium vulputate sapien sit amet sodales.

 </div>
```

Comment: Yep.  Exact same thing for me and traced it down to pointer-events.  Seems like since the latest update it's ignored - so annoying.  In my case it's just an overlay fade effect that's really only applicable to desktop anyway so hopefully a media query resolves it for Android.  Wish you luck in your case.

Comment: looks like it has been reported by a bug has been filed.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1011866&q=pointer-events&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Comment: Comment #12 has a proposed workaround for those affected in the meantime pertaining to a "non-1" opacity: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1011866#c12

Comment: @manafire ive actually tried that solution when i first saw it, but it didnt seem to make a difference. here's hoping to a quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!! Maybe new Chrome version not supporting this technique. Make a try with following code snippet:

```
.scrollable_content {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 11;
    opacity: .8;
}
```

I don't think this may give the same output as you defined, but it looks somewhat better.

Comment: actually the code above is just a pseudo simplified code to show the problem. im not trying to do a color overlay haha. and i need to have the scrollable content below the overlay layer.

usually i have a popup layer hiding somewhere waiting for a trigger.

Comment: Ohh!! Yes, I understand the scenario. But I'm also using same property to prevent the scroll of own element.. So now I have to look on it.